# how to make sure that data assigned to a variable before going through the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

The code fails because it is waiting for view model which has quite a big size data (that's why I put $onInit but it seems not working). Once I debug it and after a certain period of time, the code runs smoothly, which means before assigning values to the variable, it's going through to check the length of the array. How can I make sure that data loaded first before everything else?

```
this.$onInit = function () {
    $scope.viewModel = viewModel; 
};

$scope.trueOrFalse= Array($scope.viewModel.length).fill(false);
```

Comment: How are you loading `viewModel` ? the value which is assigned to `$scope.viewModel`

Comment: Assign it like so $scope.viewModel = viewModel ? viewModel : false; this checks if viewModel exists and if not assigns a default value.